# How can I start work on database in Hybrid app?

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

I am a beginner to Ionic framework. I have gone through the crash course available at the http://ionicframework.com/

How can I start using the Sqlite DB in my hybrid app?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

ngCordova if you are on Ionic 1: 
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/

Ionic Native if you are on Ionic 2: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/sqlite/